# Python generators; two apparently identical programs work differently

Tags: python, generator, sieve

The program below [Python 3.4] is a simple Eratosthenes sieve:

```
from itertools import *
def excl(ns,pr):
    return (i for i in ns if i%pr)
def sieve(ns):
    while True:
        pr=next(ns)
        yield pr
        ns=excl(ns,pr)
        # ns=(i for i in ns if i%pr)
r=list(islice(sieve(count(2)),10))
```

which produces [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]. OK. Uncommenting the line which inlines excl(), and commenting the call, gives [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]. Why?

Is it related to troubles expected when modyfing a sequence inside a loop which iterates over it?

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the `pr` referred to by the generator expression is the **same `pr` that you modify** in the next iteration of your while loop, so every number that is not divisible by the previous 'prime' number is treated as 'prime'. Which itself modifies `pr` and so in. In the `excl` function, the `pr` that you refer to is the one passed as an argument, which never changes.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand this answer. The prime pr doesn't change in excl (nor  in the gen.expression), it changes within the loop, and this context is identical for the inlined and 'call' version. BTW I removed an erroneous remark about filter().

Comment: @JerzyKarczmarczuk  According to [PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/), if a name is used within a code block(nested function), but it is not bound there and is not declared global, the use is treated **as a reference to** the nearest enclosing function region. As it applies to your case, the generator expression is a function under the hood, and it does not define the variable `pr`, so its `pr` is a **reference** to the `pr` in the enclosing function (`sieve`). Which means that when the `pr` in `sieve` changes, so does the `pr` in the generator expression.